Honoree Profile not being respected, a Membership receipt contains Individual Profile fields
CiviCRM 5.74.4, Wordpress.
The default Honoree profile contains only 4 fields: (First/Last name, email).
This works well for Contribution receipts. However, Membership Receipts outputs the Individual Profile fields  
At templates level, both receipts have the same code ( below ) so this must've been something else. Please advise.
{foreach from=$honoreeProfile item=value key=label}


While a cause is not known, a quick fix for the "Memberships - Receipt (on-line)" template:
 {foreach from=$honoreeProfile item=value key=label}
 <!--  empty values check -->
  {if $value != ""}
    <tr>
      <td {$labelStyle}>
        {$label}
      </td>
      <td {$valueStyle}>
        {$value}
      </td>
    </tr>
   {/if}
  {/foreach}

